# Bulk upsert in ArangoJS?

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

I have found that I can `.save(objects)` which creates objects if the key doesn't exist. I have found that I can `.bulkUpdate(objects)` which updates objects whose keys exist.

My question is: how do I do a bulk upsert? If the key exists, update it (merge), if it doesn't, create it.

Is there a way to do this without a lot of overhead?

Is it acceptable to do this?

```
db.collection("threads").bulkUpdate(keyedThreads);
db.collection("threads").save(keyedThreads);
```

Answer (score 2):

[@pluma](https://github.com/pluma) (ArangoDB) [wrote](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/issues/325) on 9 Jun 2017:

> Upsert is only available via AQL. There is no collection.upsert method.

And [@fceller](https://github.com/fceller) (ArangoDB) added:

> One of the major issues with upsert is that you access to old data. This can easily be handled in AQL, but not in a simple call to an upsert endpoint. Therefore we decided against such a call and instead implemented it in AQL.

Looks like there won't ever be a native implementation of `collection.bulkUpsert`; however you can create your own helper function using AQL's [UPSERT](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-upsert.html) and [MERGE](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#merge) functions.

<kbd>TypeScript</kbd> Example:

```js
/**
 * Upserts (merges) the content of the documents with the given documents and
 * optionally returns an array containing the documents’ metadata.
 *
 * @param {string|ArangoDB.Collection} collection - collection to use
 * @param {Document[]} documents - list of documents to upsert
 * @param opts? - optionally aggregate a result {inserted:number,updated:number}
 *  also see https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-upsert.html
 */
export async function bulkUpsert(
    collection: string | DocumentCollection,
    documents: Array<ArangoDB.DocumentData>,
    { aggregate, ...upsertOptions }: {
        ignoreRevs?: boolean,
        exclusive?: boolean,
        aggregate?: boolean
    } = {}
): Promise<{inserted:number,updated:number} | true>
{
    return await (
        await db.query({
            query:  'FOR doc IN @documents'
                  + ' UPSERT { _key: doc._key } INSERT doc UPDATE MERGE(OLD, doc)'
                  + ' IN '+(typeof collection === 'string' ? collection : collection.name)
                  + ' OPTIONS '+JSON.stringify(upsertOptions)
                  + (aggregate ?
                    ' COLLECT AGGREGATE inserted = SUM(OLD ? 0 : 1), updated = SUM(OLD ? 1 : 0)'
                  + ' RETURN {inserted,updated}' :
                    ' RETURN true'),
            bindVars: {documents}
        })
    ).next();
}
```

<sup>Source: [collection.bulkUpsert.ts Gist](https://gist.github.com/RienNeVaPlus/942cf74369037ad8f00e5d176ffe1773)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

REST Insert has the overwrite option. That is probably what you are looking for.

https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/blob/master/src/collection.ts#L721

If not you need to use the AQL UPSERT.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't that replace documents instead of merge them?

Comment: @LukePighetti you are right. If you do not just want to sync data from your application to the database you would need to write an AQL query that uses the UPSERT statement. There is no upsert REST / document handler.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `ArangoDB >= 3.7` and `arangojs >= 7.5.0`
[https://arangodb.github.io/arangojs/latest/modules/*collection*.html#collectioninsertoptions](https://arangodb.github.io/arangojs/latest/modules/_collection_.html#collectioninsertoptions)

```js
const db = new Database();
const collection = db.collection("some-collection");
const result = await collection.saveAll(
  [
    { _key: "a", color: "blue", count: 1 },
    { _key: "b", color: "red", count: 2 },
  ],
  { overwriteMode: "update" }
);
```